# PDF: Insert some optically hidden text "behind" another object?

Tags: text, adobe-acrobat

Is there an easy way to insert some text which shall be invisible, but still exist in the OCR'd / plaintext version of an PDF, using Adobe Acrobat Pro?

I'd imagine the text to be inserted behind some white text-box, which shall serve as "white" background of the current existing text.

The purpose is to embed text which could be found and read by automated pdf-parser scripts / bots but are not directly visible for humans while reading the document.

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: You can insert paper colored text to the layout. There was an era when my boss (a promoted ordinary worker ) started to exploit his former colleagues by forcing them to prepare ready to distribute files of technical subjects too difficult to create by himself. He was promoted because he had learned that it pays off to hang there where promotions are allocated, not there where they might be earned. When we saw that he presented even our original creations as his own work and removed the original source we started to make PDFs and insert background colored texts about his behaviour.

Comment: (continued) It was useless to try to complain because he had became a respected member in the local club of skunks.

Comment: I don't think you need to do that TBH.  Acrobat can scan text in an image and make the image searchable. Here are a couple of youtube video tutorials to help you: [the first](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=faPiUpXPKFk&ab_channel=Acrofacts) to create the OCR scan for the image, and [the second](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AKd345KIwLs&ab_channel=Acrofacts) to correct the OCR erros. These steps won't remove the image, just make it searchable. The OCR'd text itself will not be visible.

Comment: Funny story, thanks for sharing. The only downside is: I also want it to be "invisible" for non-technical ppl opening the file on their PCs. If I insert text which is background-colored - they will see it immediately when "selecting" the text.

Comment: @tim even if there is a object above they can still select it.

Comment: What is the real reason you want to do this? Perhaps some standardized solution already exists? I'm thinking about using meta data for example?

Comment: Actually I want to trick CV-reading bots, i.e. bots that scan uploaded curriculum vitaes into "forwarding" my CV to the next level because of some keywords somewhere in the hidden area. Without actually having them been mentioned in the text which is readable when ppl open the PDF on their computer :)

Comment: @joojaa: Maybe yes, maybe no. Not sure whether it'll be selected if it's behind some object. I know the text will somewhere in the document obviously, e.g. if you open the PDF in Notepad++ or similarly. But whether it'll be selectable, not sure

Comment: Texts which are unreadable small for people can still be red by machines if they are text objects.

Comment: It will be selectable in most PDF viewers what you do is you drag the selection over the whole page, or hit ctrl+a, then it selects all text be it under a object or not. This highlights the text and it shines trough the object. Its just as obvious as paper colored text. So im afraid this may or may not work as intended. Instead you can make the font very small.

Comment: There can be same size other objects which contain same looking other shapes, say an ornament which has say 500 separate shapes, one of them is the text.

Comment: About tricking bots. Reminds of how the web was in the old days. A site could have tons of "hidden" words in the bottom to trick search engines. These tricks don't work today as semantics, links and other aspects are also taken into consideration. Are you sure the bots are that stupid? It's not that I think it's immoral really, but of course if you add irrelevant words it does seem a bit in a gray zone and might backfire if someone thinks you are "too clever". If the words aren't irrelevant, wouldn't it be more honest to just incorporate them in your text?

Comment: I guess you just need to be a bit cleverer than the average. And yes, indeed it doesn't make any sense to add to many very irrelevant words. But to add one or two keywords which might be relevant to the position but not really possible to put it in previous job descriptions seems to do the trick. But yes, in the end, no one will probably ever know whether or works or not